# Is it mandatory to check FileExists() before DeleteFile()?

Tags: delphi

Some time ago, I do not remember where, I read about a best practice in delphi.

Instead of this:

```pascal
if FileExists(MyFile) then begin
        if not DeleteFile(MyFile) then
                ShowMessage('Unable to delete file');
end;
```

write this:

```pascal
if not DeleteFile(MyFile) then
        ShowMessage('Unable to delete file');
```

What are the pro and cons of he second?

Comment: in the first method the user does not gets any message at all if the file does not exists, so he dont know if it was deleted or not. In the second the user will always be notified if the deletion failed. So which is better depends on what you want your users to see

Comment: Here is two use cases: 1. you expect that file may not exists and this is not an error; 2. file must exists and if it not, then we get an error.

Comment: In the first method, the file could conceivably be deleted by another process between the FileExists check and the DeleteFile call, and thus render the FileExists check redundant, as you can't count on it.

Comment: @zed: A better way would be to just call DeleteFile and if it fails, call GetLastError to determine the _reason_ it failed. If ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND you know it was because the file didn't exist. if ERR_ACCESS_DENIED you know the file existed, but you weren't able to delete it (it could be open in another process or marked as Read/Only). This way you can handle all use cases without any chance of coming to the wrong conclusion based on the result of an invalidated FileExists call.

Comment: @Heartware ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND is also possible I believe

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: True... And there may be a couple of other errors as well... Such as "Drive Not Ready" if the file was located on a USB drive that has since been removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I read the code in your question as a desire to delete a file, and report an error only if the file exists, and cannot be deleted.

---

Checking whether or not a file exists before attempting to delete it is not best practise. In fact, doing so is a classic anti pattern.

The correct pattern is to attempt to delete the file directly. If it fails then check the reason for failure. This will tell you whether or not the file exists, or if the deletion failed for some other reason. On Windows this means using the Win32 API function named `DeleteFile` and checking its return value for success or failure. In case of failure, call `GetLastError` to obtain the reason for failure.

Doing this in a cross platform way is not completely trivial, and I don't think the RTL offers such functionality.

---

It is also well worth pointing out that your two blocks of code are not interchangeable. They have different behaviour. The first block treats file not existing as success. The second treats that as error. If you wish to reproduce the first behaviour with only a single function call then you need to discriminate based on error codes, as described above.

Comment: Isn't DeleteFile() from SysUtils.pas cross-plaform?

Comment: @Arnaud yes, but discrimination of error cause is not part of that api, or is it?

Comment: It returns a boolean for success or failure. The OP doesn't mean about low-level error cause, just if it succeeded or not.

Comment: @Arnaud Not really. The code that checks whether or not the file exists treats it not existing as success.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `FileExists()` is pointless.

The file may exist, but not be deletable - e.g. if it is read/only, or locked by another process. It won't be faster than calling `DeleteFile()`.

So the 2nd version is preferred:

```
if not DeleteFile(MyFile) then
    ShowMessage('Unable to delete file');
```

Note: `DeleteFile()` from SysUtils.pas is cross-platform, and returns a boolean for success - since the comments and some answer only deal with the raw API call from Windows.pas.

Comment: Very much worth while pointing out that the two blocks of code in question are not interchangeable. The second block, repeated in this answer, treats file not found as an error.

Comment: It al depends on what kind of behavior you want. But when you expect to delete a file and you’re not able, then there’s no need for fileexists. When you want to point out the reason of the failure to the user, for a crossplatform sollution, you could use FileExists to detect a missing file vs an existing file which cannot be deleted...